# Showing 'old' value in table until actual commit

Tags: commit, oracle-adf

I have a table with an attribute that needs to be changed with a checkbox in a table (it's the  status of a row that gets upgraded). Apart from the column with the checkboxes, the attribute is also represented textually (readonly) in another column.

Ticking the checkbox and committing gives the proper behavior. However, if I sort the table at any column, after ticking the box but before committing, the textfield changes it's value accordingly, while it keeps showing the 'old' value if I choose not to sort the table. My client wants consistency by having the textual column to show the 'old' (uncommitted) data after sorting (while not loosing the ticks in the checkboxes), and only update this after the actual commit.

For now, I've tried to make a transient attribute which copies the value. I told this dummy attribute to never recalculate. However, sorting seems to do some kind of a requery, making this transient attribute to change along: ommitting my very purpose for it.

Any solution to keep showing the 'old' data until commit would be greatly appreciated!
I'm working on it with JDeveloper 11.1.1.4

Comment: Do you have any sample code or data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. What you mean when you say "ticking the box but before commiting"?. If you re-sort your data is probable that your code is making a new query to the database and get the value from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make transient values not refresh on sorting table columns, create the transient attribute in EO first and then use it in VO.